# Wicket : enabling a panel component while entire panel is disabled explicitly

Tags: wicket-1.5

Currently I have a panel, where say I have 10 text fields and 10 dropdowns. I want to disable all components in the panel except for 1 text field. Currently what I am doing is call setenabled false for all components in the panel and set enabled true for only 1 component. Rather than doing this, I would prefer to disable the whole panel and to enable only 1 particular component in that panel. But this is not working. Is it possible in wicket? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this interface: `IVisitor`

```
visitChildren(new IVisitor<Component, Object>() {
        @Override
        public void component(Component object, IVisit<Object> visit) {
            object.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```

Here `visitChildren()` is a function of `MarkupContainer` which your `Panel` is.

Or create a function:

```
public static void setEnabled(boolean enabled, Component... components) {
    for (Component component : components) {
        component.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
}
```

and use like this:

```
setEnabled(false, textfield1, textfield2, dropdown1, dropdown2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable the panel and override the exceptional component's isEnabled() function to return true. /When using link, then override protected boolean isLinkEnabled() and public boolean canCallListenerInterface(Method method) as well!/
When you have it, try it and if you get ListenerInvocationNotAllowedException then check what causes it. It is well written in log. You may also get other exceptions, try debug them but i believe that all are resolveable.
My answer is based on Wicket 1.6 (proof of concept reached) but probably a solution for 1.5 as well..

My exceptional component was a DownloadLink. Here's the example:

```
DownloadLink documentLink = new DownloadLink("documentLink", getFileModel(question), new PropertyModel<String>(getDefaultModelObject(), "answer.documentName")){
        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean isLinkEnabled() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canCallListenerInterface(Method method) {
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Comment: _Disable the panel and override the exceptional component's isEnabled() function to return true_ does not work for me for one checkbox in a Panel i wicket 6.18 and 6.24

Comment: Which implementation of CheckBox did you use? (As checkbox is an interface..)

Comment: Checkbox is a class: https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/CheckBox.html